# How to register event handler for WebBrowser.ScriptNotify Event

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

I am trying to invoke a C# function from JavaScript used in my `WP8 HTML5 App`.
I am trying to use  [WebBrowser.ScriptNotify Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)  to do so.

In my html5 code I have written:

```
<button onclick="window.external.Notify('clearTextBox');">clear textbox</button>
```

But button is shown in app when I run it using WPEmulator.
I don't know how to register event handler for it. Please help.

**P.S.** I am not using Phonegap (i.e. Apache Cordova )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function in your btn handler:

```
<button onclick='function(){ window.external.Notify('clearTextBox'); }'>clear textbox</button>
```

In `XAML` define `ScriptNotify` handler and set `IsScriptEnabled = true`, for example:

```
 <phone:WebBrowser
   x:Name="Browser"
   IsScriptEnabled="true"
   ScriptNotify="BrowserScriptNotify">
</phone:WebBrowser>
```

Add event handler to code behind:

```
private void BrowserScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do your business here
        }
```

Comment: I did so,but it did not worked for me, when I `clear text box` click nothing happens.  

I did wrote `Browser.Navigate(new Uri("www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));` in the body of event handler.

Comment: Please help and tell if I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: That worked finally, I wrote a function instead of inplace in JS. 
`<button onclick='func()'>clear textbox</button>`                 function func(){ window.external.Notify("clearTextBox"); }

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. One more thing how to get result back from event handler?

Comment: I can think of calling JS from C# now. Is it the only way?